# Recommendation to improve wp-admin panel performance

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, docker, nginx

Recommendation to improve wp-admin panel performance : Please provide the suggestions and way to identify the bottlenecks in wordpress admin panel issue. It is a multisite and it has 3rd party plugins enabled . How to identify plugin conflict and which plugin is causing perf/ memory issues.  All these php-fpm, nginx are running in DOcker container

Issues observed: 
During login
During Post create new page loading

Comment: I've never found a better way to debug performance issues in WP installations than to clone into a test environment and disable plugins one by one.

Comment: you could use the network tab in your development tool (if on chrome) - and see what is loading when - you might be able to see something there

Comment: You could post your question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ as you might be able to get a fast and good answer :)

Comment: What load is the app and db server running at when things are slow?

Comment: did you consider [Microcaching with Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/benefits-of-microcaching-nginx/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your inputs. 
I have identified the problem and resolve it . The problem is with the Network file system and the php script takes more time to read it because the uploaded assets total size is in GB's and the wordpress framework built in Filter will do recursive call to calculate the size. I have used Debug bar slow action and filter plugin to identify which action / filter is taking more time.

Solution: And in admin panel of multisite, there is a setting if you enable then it will skip calculating the size of the disk - Now site is very fast. But will lose the functionality of restricting users from uploading ex. i define 2 gb for each site, then that functionality to restrict users from the disk quota of 2 GB  will be disabled. Is there a way to tune that stuff ? Kindly provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is step by step guide to identify performance issues.

1. If server isn't in production or if it doesn't matter very much, try to switch to any default WordPress theme (TwentySeventeen for example) and look if anything changes.
2. You can deactivate all plugins and look if it helps. If yes - try to turn on plugins one by one and this will help you to identify which plugin causes the performance issues.
3. Try to install a free plugin called Debug Bar (you can do it from Plugins-Add New), it will show you slow things on your website

   [image: debug bar plugin]
4. Inspecting your browser console also might help.

Comment: Before going through your post itself i found the solution, but You deserve the bounty points. Your inputs are more valuable but the screen shot shown is related to Query Monitor plugin and not related to debug bar plugin :) . Saw ur website and have created more plugins - you are simply awesome :) and a wp expertise.

Comment: thanks once again :) Solution: And in admin panel of multisite, there is a setting if you enable then it will skip calculating the size of the disk - Now site is very fast. But will lose the functionality of restricting users from uploading ex. i define 2 gb for each site, then that functionality to restrict users from the disk quota of 2 GB will be disabled. Is there a way to tune that stuff ? Kindly provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Since this issue is caused by the interaction of both your code (plugins) and your production environment, you need some tool that takes all of that into account when attempting to measure the cause.

I really like New Relic for this. It is a paid product, but with the free trial you might be able to diagnose your issue. They have a WordPress integration that will show you specifically how many seconds/ms each action hook and plugin is taking.

Answer (score 1):

There are several php performance tools such as XHProf which can help you determine the cause of the problem.

Please don't forget to tell us what the problem was, by updating your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Can you pls give us a list of PlugIns installed!?

I could tell you for some that they are a waste of memory from my experience...

Are you using i.e. a visual composer plug in, the one named like that is the most worst backend plug in regarding its needs of ressorces and in premium themes it comes most often combined with master slider revolution, which has also crazy memory needs...

Do you have in general many plug ins, so let's say more then 10 to 20? Do you need all of them? Which are the ones that load when you edit a page in the backend?

If you really need all of them think about renting a better server... ;-)

Comment: It is hard to say in generall how to identify the problem without more infos about your insallation, because it depends on so many individual factors... As server speed, size of your site and so on!

In genral wordpress is not that efficient with the database management for bigger sites and you said you have a multisite installation, with how many sites round about!? :)

More sadly many, many PlugINs are even more worse than wp core regarding their efficiency....

Answer (score 1):

What I have found during my fight with slow wp-admin is the **heartbeat wordpress functionality** which is responsible for autosaving and making thousands of copies of same post. 
It sets autosave interval. 
Its not a performance-killer but in my case (woocommerce with few thousand records) it helped a bit to improved speed of admin panel, may be usefull for you aswell.

You might trying in your functions.php adding the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'stop_heartbeat', 1 );
    function stop_heartbeat() {
    wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to make a website backup on another server and check the problem. If problems is still there, deactivate plugins one by one.